# How do I populate a javascript variable with data fetched from a database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just implemented this autocomplete thing: http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/index.html.
And it works ok with a setup like this:

```
var suggests = ["head", "hello", "heart", "health", "horizontal", "horizont", "hormonotherapy"];
$("#autocomplete").asuggest(suggests, {'delimiters':':', 'minChunkSize':3, 'endingSymbols':'] '});
```

- By the way; Is there any reason to why I can't use `[` as the delimiters? It doesn't respont to that character at all - which is a huge bummer...

Anyway; I vould like to populate the `suggests`-variable from data fetched from a database when the user types.

I just tried this approach:

```
$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(){
    var suggests = $.getJSON('assets/scripts/getExtra.json.php',{ term: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        return data;
    });
    $("#autocomplete").asuggest(suggests, {'delimiters':':', 'minChunkSize':3, 'endingSymbols':'] '});
});
```

This did not work. The console shows that it returns a string with values as expected, but it's not detected by the asuggest-function..
*And when I look at it now, I can see it trows a request for each character, and includes all character in the searchfield (textarea)..*

Any suggestion to how I can change/update the `suggests`-variable over AJAX each time a new search is initiated?

I need to be able to do a search like this:
"Start out by filling a container with [this] and [that]. Then add some [thing] at the end."

Everytime `[` is typed, I need to clear out/empty the `suggests`-variable, and initiate a new search to the database.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) you have a fully functional autocomplete example using JSONP as datasource.

Comment: Just tried out that for a while, but couldn't find out how to make it work the way I described: To only do a search when I type `[`in the textarea. After that, adding `] `at the end, and just continue writing..

Comment: oh, you aren't using jQuery UI Autocomplete - for which that example is for. It does not seem that the library you use has build-in support for jquery, so the answer from @mcv is probably your best choice then.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your AJAX call is done asynchronously. So when the call `$.getJSON()` returns, your success callback hasn't been called yet. So when it then calls `$("#autocomplete").asuggest(suggests, {})`, your variable has no data (and I'm not sure it ever will).

Try this instead:

```
$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(){
    $.getJSON('assets/scripts/getExtra.json.php',{ term: $(this).val() }, function(suggests) {
        $("#autocomplete").asuggest(suggests, {'delimiters':':', 'minChunkSize':3, 'endingSymbols':'] '});
    });
});
```

By doing it inside the callback, you initialize the autosuggest after you get the data.

*Edit:* If this doesn't work, could you try:

```
$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(){
    $.getJSON('assets/scripts/getExtra.json.php',{ term: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data);
        var suggests = ["head", "hello", "heart", "health", "horizontal", "horizont", "hormonotherapy"];
        $("#autocomplete").asuggest(suggests, {'delimiters':':', 'minChunkSize':3, 'endingSymbols':'] '});
    });
});
```

Comment: god suggestion, but didn't work.. I think I have to do some editing inside the plugin script. Like someplace where each search is initiated. Doing it outside just takes all the characters into account when doing a search, and not only the word(s) after `[` until it closes again...

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea how .asuggest works. I'm just helping out with how to do the AJAX properly. Can you verify that the success function gets called at least? And with what data? I'm also wondering if you '[' might get interpreted as the start of an array somehow.

Comment: The call is successful, and data is returned. It just doesn't get detected by the `$.asuggest`. But I decided to have this inline at the bottom of my page. This way I can just query the database, and then put the returned result directly into the `js.variable`. It works, for now, since there isn't that many results..

Comment: If you log the data in the callback, the data is there? And if you pass static data to asuggest, it works, but if you pass the data, it doesn't? Because that would be really weird. I've added some debugging code to my answer. Could you try that?

Answer (score 0):

May not be related, but, this might be helpful to someone. Calling `$("#autocomplete").keyup()` manually once you have fetched your data will show you updated suggestions:

so your code might look like:

```
$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(){
    $.getJSON('assets/scripts/getExtra.json.php',{ term: $(this).val() }, function(suggests) {
        $("#autocomplete").asuggest(suggests, {'delimiters':':', 'minChunkSize':3, 'endingSymbols':'] '});
        $("#autocomplete").keyup(); // this line should do the trick
    });
});
```